# Windows Phone browser background agent

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, browser

Okay so I have a Windows Phone app that has a web browser object that displays a page that plays audio (with an htmlaudioelement).
I'd like to keep this audio playing (which means keeping that browser active) when my app closes.
I know this is possible because mobile internet explorer does it.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve something similar?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot in the way you describe.

WebBrowser is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) in background tasks.

The only thing you can do, is manually connect to the audio source and use a [Background audio agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394039%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to play the audio.

As an aside: Just because a native app (IE) can do it, does not automatically mean your app can do it. There's a ton of functionality that's opened only for native apps on the phone.

Comment: Okay thats kind of the conclusion I was coming to, which is disappointing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 for "There's a ton of functionality that's opened only for native apps on the phone". This is very correct for the case of WP7 !

Answer (score 2):

If your audio keeps playing in Internet Explorer Mobile, use [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to launch the URL in IE.

Comment: Good point - may be a good solution for you. You do lose control at that point though.

Comment: This really isn't a solution. The point is my app is a music player. Just opening the audio source in IE is useless.

Comment: Well then, MediaStreamSource and BackgroundAudioPlayer are your friends.